Is there any two-coordinate system where X, Y is the same point as Y, X?
Is there any two-coordinate system where e.g., (10,36) is the same point as (36,10)?
You see we here at the Rescue Centre are at our wits' end. Half our reports come in with latitude first, half with longitude first. Yes, I know about Plus Codes, but I am curious, has anybody ever fool proofed a two coordinate system? Even for just plane coordinates?

Yes, using a folded single coordinate axis.

 2.


The first image is the usual two-axis grid from elementary school. In the second image we only use one quadrant (northeast), and a folded single coordinate axis, "25th Street", which starts in the east, makes a sharp right turn, then
continues north.
There can only be one 10th Street and only one 36th Street, so "the corner of "10th and 36th" is the same place as "the corner of 36th and 10th". Indeed 3600 10th Street is also the same place as 1000 36th Street.

Incomprehensible.

By interpolating and expanding system 2 with more L-shaped numbered streets, this grid covers the northeast half-plane, where intersections have a low E-W street number and a high N-S street number. Now the rescue centre just ignores the southwest half, by pretending coordinate pairs are unordered and the lower number definitely means the N-S street segment.

https://www.jidanni.org/geo/house_numbering/grids/algorithms/single_axis/single_axis.html
